# Testing for a result from array_search

Tags: php, arrays

I am processing a CSV authored by a remote system.  I don't want to assume they won't change what fields they provide or their order so I am parsing a header row for the indices in the CSV of fields and mapping these into an array I can use for lookups and updates.

Thing is the way I am doing it tests false for index zero:

```
foreach ($field_map_array as $local_field => $silverpop_field) {
    if ($idx = array_search($silverpop_field, $fields)) {
        $local_to_sp[$local_table][$local_field] = $idx;
    } // index found
}
```

What's a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns an integer if it finds the needle, and `FALSE` otherwise, so test it explicitly using the [`!==` / not identical operator](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
foreach ($field_map_array as $local_field => $silverpop_field) {
    if (($idx = array_search($silverpop_field, $fields)) !== FALSE) {
        $local_to_sp[$local_table][$local_field] = $idx;
    } // index found
}
```

Here's how [the manual](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) describes the difference between `!=` (not equal) and `!==` (not identical) (emphasis added):

> $a != $b  Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b **after type juggling.**
>
> $a !== $b     Not identical   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or **they are not of the same type.**

The problem with your code is that `if(0)` is interpreted as `if(0 != FALSE)`. Type juggling lets it cast FALSE to the integer 0, and `0 != 0` is obviously false. With `!==` type juggling doesn't occur, so `0 !== FALSE` is true (since they're not the same type).

I'd recommend using `===` and `!==` whenever possible, since they are more predictable, and predictable code tends to be less buggy and easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the response! When I used your line I was not getting the result I expected but when I instead used $idx = array_search($silverpop_field, $fields);  AND THEN if ($idx !== FALSE) { that worked as I hoped.  I like the one line approach though but I'm not clear why the result didn't work?  Also tried it with TRUE instead of FALSE.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh Sorry, I mixed up how `if` statements work (doh). You need `!==` in this case. If you do `if (($idx = array_search($silverpop_field, $fields)) !== FALSE)` it should work.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  I'll be using the === going forward!